# GeoTools WFS Transaction modifyfeatures problem: WFSException: Invalid value for property the_geom

Tags: geoserver, wfs, java, geotools, wfs-t

I'm using GeoTools WFS package to update features in GeoServer. I don't have any problem with updating literal attributes, but when I tried to modify the geometry of features I got the following error from the log of tomcat:

```
org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: Invalid value for property the_geom
```

I'm using following snippet of code to modify features:

```
String wkt = "POINT(30 40)";    
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
WKTReader reader = new WKTReader(geometryFactory);
Geometry jtsGeometry = reader.read(wkt); 

Name geoname = featureStore.getSchema().getGeometryDescriptor().getName();
Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("update"); 
featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
featureStore.modifyFeatures(geoname, jtsGeometry, filter);

transaction.commit();
```

Also I used FeatureWriter library and I got the same error as well.

Comment: What is the XML being sent? Is the WFS geometry called `the_geom`?

Comment: Thanks Ian, I edited the code, I got the geometry name from the featureStore which was retrieved from WFSDataStore. As I said other parts of code is correct, because I don't have any problem with literal properties. I thought if there isn't any problem in this code, maybe I miss some special config in the geoserver, but geoserver worked correctly. I check geoserver sending a WFSTransaction XML through HTTP Post. As you said I should check generated XML request, but how could I get the xml request from the transaction or featureStrore objects?

Comment: Look in the geoserver log

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem by downgrading WFS service version in the connection parameters of WFSDataStoreFactory. By default, WFS service version is 2.0.0, which is got exception in updating geometries. I used following code to downgrade my WFS service request version:

```
WFSDataStoreFactory wfsDataStoreFactory = new WFSDataStoreFactory();
URL url = WFSDataStoreFactory.createGetCapabilitiesRequest(
                new URL("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs"), 
                new Version("1.1.0"));
Map<String, Serializable> connectionParams = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
connectionParams.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.URL.key, url);
connectionParams.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.USERNAME.key, "admin");
connectionParams.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.PASSWORD.key, "geoserver");
```

I'm using geotools version 28.1 & geoserver version 22.0.
I think there is a problem in updating of geometries of WFS features using geotools `featureStore.modifyFeatures` method when it configured on default version of WFS (2.0.0).